# SQL - Filter out only first record in SQL (Amazon Redshift)

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have this one query that I am using to pull data from one table that store customer data along with their feedback. However I have an issue where the same customer (cust_id) has more that one entry. How could I modify this to only return the first row (based on timestamp) and ignore all other records..

I am using Amazon redshift.

```
with q1 as 
(select cust_id,
       sum(case when response <= 6 then 1 else 0 end) as bad,
       sum(case when response between 7 and 8 then 1 else 0 end) as good
       from customers 
       group by cust_id
       order by 1 DESC ,last_visit_datetime desc),
q2 as (select cust_id,rating as neg_rating,response as neg_response from customers 
where rating is not null
order by neg_rating asc, last_visit_datetime desc )
select DISTINCT q1.cust_id,q1.good,q1.bad,q2.neg_response,q2.neg_rating
from q1 join q2 on q1.cust_id = q2.cust_id
```

Could anyone assist, thanks..

Comment: Did you try to use `ROW_NUMBER () OVER
(
[ PARTITION BY expr_list ]
[ ORDER BY order_list ]
) ` and then equalizing the returning value to 1( if ties must be included using `DENSE_RANK` might be preferable ).

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 2):

Use `row_number` to get one row per cust_id and then do the aggregation.

```
select cust_id,
sum(case when response <= 6 then 1 else 0 end) as bad,
sum(case when response between 7 and 8 then 1 else 0 end) as good
from (select c.*,row_number() over(partition by cust_id order by last_visit_datetime desc) as rnum 
      from customers c
     ) c
where rnum=1 
group by cust_id
```